# How to limit access to Mysql database for a developer

Tags: mysql, security

So we've got a MYSQL database with very sensitive information and we want to prevent it from being exported by a developer/admin who has access to it, while still allowing them to access database while working on their duties.
In simple terms we want to prohibit mass select on specific tables.
Ideally it would be an option to disable mass select, something like limit 0, 1 enforcement for all SELECT queries on specific tables. Is it possible to configure MYSQL like that? Any other ideas how to prevent database from being exported?

Comment: In such cases developers should develop on a impersonized sample of data and have no access to the production instance.

Comment: I know, but this is not the perfect world :-)

Comment: newtover's suggestion is easier than your question:  See [Selecting random rows ...](https://www.warpconduit.net/2011/03/23/selecting-a-random-record-using-mysql-benchmark-results/)

Comment: Well, if a developer can fetch one row, its simple to fetch all rows with consecutive queries. So you can not avoid this case. If, by any privacy reasons, a developer should not have access to all data, probably he should not have access to any real data?

Answer (score 1):

Any solution I can think of when someone needs to access your production data within MySQL and you want to apply the principle of least privilege leads to separation of users and to the page on [GRANT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html) command in MySQL documentation.

But as I said in a comment to you question, it is much easier to develop a procedure to generate an impersonated sample of your data, so that your developers would not have access to the production data.